# Spring data jpa operation between table views

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

in my spring data application i have two TABLE VIEW mapped:
the first view

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="VD_CONT")
@NamedQuery(name="VdContr.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM VdContr d")

public class VdContr  {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="CONTR_ID")
    private Long id;    
    
    @Column(name="CF")
    private String cf;

 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="vdcontr")
private List<VdArr> vdArr;
}
```

and the second view

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="VD_ARR")
@NamedQuery(name="VdArr.findAll", query="SELECT v FROM VdArr v")
public class VdArr {

    
         @Id
        @Column(name="ARR_ID")
        private Long id;
    
        
        @Column(name="FK_CONTR_ID")
        private Long fkContrId;

      @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
      public VdContr vdcontr;

    
}
```

If i put a relationship "OneToMany" and "ManyToOne" (1, first view : many, second view), i receive errors.
My question is: is it possibile create a relationship between two table view?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a @JoinColumn to VdContr.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "vdcontr_id", nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, views are mapped in the same way as tables.

By looking at your classes, the problem is that Hibernate cannot find the correct join column. You need to specify it.

Also, in your `VdArr` you should delete the `fkContrId`, because hibernate will need to use this column to map the `VdContr` relationship.

By looking at your code, the join column is `FK_CONTR_ID`, so you need to specify it by using `@JoinColumn`.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "VD_ARR")
@NamedQuery(name = "VdArr.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM VdArr v")
public class VdArr {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ARR_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_CONTR_ID")
    public VdContr vdcontr;

}
```